# How to skip multiline comments with multiple comment closing tags using java

Tags: java, parsing, comments

I have a java program which reads a text file and adds and removes some portion of the contents. It works with the inline and multiple line comments also in the text files.

For example the following portion will be skipped

```
// inline comment

/*multiple
 *comment
 */
```

I am having a problem with a case where multiple comment closing occurs, for example

```
/**
*This
* is
*/
* a multiple line comment
*/
```

In this case as soon as the first comment closing tag occurs the skipping of comment is stopped and the rest of the line is printed in the output file.

Here is how I an doing this

```
boolean commentStart = false;
boolean commentEnd = false;

if(line.trim().indexOf("/*") != -1) {  // start
   commentStart = true;
}

if(line.trim().indexOf("*/") != -1 && commentStart) {  // closed
   commentEnd = true;
   commentStart = false;
}

if(commentStart || (!commentStart && commentClosed)) {
    //skip line
}
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: I presume you mean nested comments, but your example doesn't demonstrate that case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes nested comments can also be a case.

Comment: According to what you showed first, you can continue examining the text until you find the next \*/, store it's position, check that no /* exist between index of first /* and the index of last \*/ you get the two positions between which you'll skip the text.

Comment: @Anila: Actually I am doing this line by line, so after a line is written or skipped the next line is independent of the previous and all I have these two variables to check with.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you restrict yourself to nested comments, you have a malformed file there. If that's ok, then you need to define what *is* a comment, if not only something that's between `/*` and `*/`. From your example, it looks like *your* definition of comment is any line that starts with `*/`, `/*` *or* `*`. In regex: `^[/\\\b]?*`.

If that works, I'd just skip lines if they match the regular expression.

Comment: According to me any line starting with /* and ending with */ and also any thing in between these two should be a comment.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then you'll have to read ahead one line. Check @Anila s answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Perl regex that will strip comments from Java taking full account of quoted strings and everything.  The only thing it doesn't grok is comments or quotes made with \uXXXX sequences.

```
sub strip_java_comments_and_quotes
{
  s!(  (?: \" [^\"\\]*   (?:  \\.  [^\"\\]* )*  \" )
     | (?: \' [^\'\\]*   (?:  \\.  [^\'\\]* )*  \' )
     | (?: \/\/  [^\n] *)
     | (?: \/\*  .*? \*\/)
   )
   !
     my $x = $1;
     my $first = substr($x, 0, 1);
     if ($first eq '/')
     {
         # Replace comment with equal number of newlines to keep line count consistent
         "\n" x ($x =~ tr/\n//);
     }
     else
     {
         # Replace quoted string with equal number of newlines to keep line count consistent
         $first . ("\n" x ($x =~ tr/\n//)) . $first;
     }
   !esxg;
}
```

I'll have a go at converting it to Java:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile(
 "(  (?: \" [^\"\\\\]*   (?:  \\\\.  [^\"\\\\]* )*  \" )" +
 "| (?: ' [^'\\\\]*   (?:  \\\\.  [^'\\\\]* )*  ' )" +
 "| (?: //  [^\\n] *)" +
 "| (?: /\\*  .*? \\*/)" +
 ")", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.COMMENTS);
 Matcher m = Pattern.matcher(entireSourceFile);
 Stringbuffer replacement = new Stringbuffer();
 while (m.find())
 {
      String match = m.group(1);
      String first = match.substring(0, 1);
      m.appendReplacement(replacement, ""); // Beware of $n in replacement string!!
      if (first.equals("/"))
      {
         // Replace comment with equal number of newlines to keep line count consistent
         replacement.append( match.replaceAll("[^\\n]", ""));
      }
      else
      {
         // Replace quoted string with equal number of newlines to keep line count consistent
         // Although Java quoted strings aren't legally allowed newlines in them
         replacement.append(first).append(match.replaceAll("[^\\n]", "")).append(first);
       }
 }
 m.appendTail(replacement);
```

Something like that!